# Product With SUMIF Function When Using ROUND Function

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a way to get the same results as the following function, but without using SUMPRODUCT, since SUMPRODUCT is not supported in Documents To Go for iPhone.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$50000="O")*ROUND($C$2:$C$50000,0))
```

I have tried using SUMIF and SUMIFS, but both result in errors. Neither likes the use of the ROUND function.

```
=SUMIF($D$2:$D$50000,"O",ROUND($B$2:$B$50000,0))    
=SUMIFS(ROUND($B$2:$B$50000),$D$2:$D$50000,"O")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried using SUMIF and SUMIFS, but both result in errors. Neither likes the use of the ROUND function

That is because `SUMPRODUCT` can take in array values while `SUMIF` cannot.

> I'm trying to find a way to get the same results as the following function, but without using SUMPRODUCT, since SUMPRODUCT is not supported in Documents To Go for iPhone.

I do not see a way to implement that **exact** functionality without having the formula or changing the spreadsheet slightly.

You can get **close** by using `=ROUND(SUMIF($D$2:$D$50000,"O",$C$2:$C$50000),0)` which will round the end value instead of each individual value.

However you could change the spreadsheet by making another column (lets say E) that is just the rounded version of column C and use `=SUMIF($D$2:$D$50000,"O",$E$2:$E$50000)`

Or you could make a **custom function** that implements the same functionality as `SUMPRODUCT` and use that.

Comment: I'll play around with it. Thanks!

Comment: It is very misleading to say that putting the `round` at the outside will give a result that is "close" to the original formula. It can be wildly different ! (e.g. with 50 times 1.001, the result is 100 vs 51, which I would not really call "close"). I like much more the solution of barry.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can use an "array formula" like this

`=SUM(IF($D$2:$D$50000="O",ROUND($C$2:$C$50000,0)))`

Not sure if Documents To Go will support array formulas? In Excel that formula needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>